how to create two figures of the same size, regardless of x-axis labels or titles in R ggplot2
I'm creating several plots with ggplot2 using the following code:
Figure 1 without x-axis labels and title:
plot1<-ggplot(data, aes(x=pred_1, y=response, fill=pred_2)) +
    geom_violin(width=0.7) +
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.05)) +
    ggtitle("") +
  ylab("response") +
  xlab("") + #no axis title
  ylim(0,3300) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("level1", "level2")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red3","green4")) +
    geom_point(data=average_data, aes(x=pred_1, y=response),position=position_dodge(width=0.7), size=4, shape=22, stroke=1, show.legend=FALSE,color="black",fill="grey") +
  geom_line(data=average_data, aes(x=pred_1,y=response,group=1),linewidth=1) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5),size=12,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 5),size=12,face="bold"),
        #axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),  # Increase font size for x-axis tick labels
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), #remove the x-axis labels
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

Figure 2 with x-axis labels and title:
plot1<-ggplot(data_2, aes(x=pred_1, y=response, fill=pred_2)) +
    geom_violin(width=0.7) +
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.05)) +
    ggtitle("") +
  ylab("response") +
  xlab("this is my x-axis title")
  ylim(0,3300) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("level1", "level2")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red3","green4")) +
    geom_point(data=average_data_2, aes(x=pred_1, y=response),position=position_dodge(width=0.7), size=4, shape=22, stroke=1, show.legend=FALSE,color="black",fill="grey") +
  geom_line(data=average_data_2, aes(x=pred_1,y=response,group=1),linewidth=1) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5),size=12,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 5),size=12,face="bold"),
        #axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),  # Increase font size for x-axis tick labels
     
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

When I plot these 2 figures, the 'panel' (i.e. the plot itself, without axes, is this the right word?) of Figure 2 (with x-axis title) is slightly smaller, because the x-axis labels take up room. In other words, the y-axis is a bit compressed, relative to figure 1 (without x-axis labels).
However, I want these two figures to have the exact same 'panel' size, regardless of the x-axis labels.
I tried to use add theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm") to set the same margins, but this doesn't work. Also tried theme(axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=10))
I got the suggestion to use coord_fix(ratio=1), but this messes up the complete figure.
In the end, I want to make a combination plot of several figures using grid.arrange, ggarrange(), or plot_grids(). There, I'd like to vertically stack figure 1 and 2, and that the x-axis labels and title of figure 2 (bottom) also serve as labels for figure 1 (top). If the size of the panel itself is not the same, it looks messy.
How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Hard to confirm without reproducible example or picture. patchwork usually works for me in similar situations.

This question and many similar questions quite often. See if this helps.

patchwork did the trick, thanks! Reason I did not provide MRE: I thought there would be some easy fix within ggplot2 itself..
